# Travelling to Germany in the 19th Century from London

Tags: 19th-century, germany, travel, victorian, ships

The time period I'm working with is the 1890s, and try as I might I'm really struggling to find the details I need, specifically how long it would take to travel from London to Leipzig at that time. 
Also, I'd love to know what kind of accommodation would a middle-class person have expected on the ship itself? Individual cabins or would they have been crammed in? I assume the ships themselves would have been steam-powered by that time. 
Anyway, any information on either of these things - or just travelling to and from Germany during that time in general - would be immensely appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Leipzig seems a bit far from the ocean to be accessed by ship...

Comment: Take a ship to Ostend or Hamburg or somewhere similar (not much slower than now) and then a train - Wikipedia has a [1861 railway map](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/54/Bahnkarte_Deutschland_1861.jpg) and things only got better after that

Comment: @Henry This railway map is more recent, as a the Lausanne-Bern railway in Switzerland which was innogurated in 1862 is on the map. EDIT: probably they included rail lines in construction ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ships were certainly steam-driven by the 1890s. For a rough calculation, figure a day from London to Calais by train and ship, then 200 miles per day by train from Calais to Leipzig. There were plenty of trains.

A comic, but basically truthful portrayal of middle-class travel at the time can be found in Jerome K Jerome's novel [Three Men on the Bummel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_Men_on_the_Bummel).